# Why is Instagram Likes Count incorrect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instagram, instagram-api

I'm using the following code to determine the total number of posts that an instagram user has liked.  This code worked locally on a small number of likes (66 total).  It iterated through pages of 20 each until it reached 66.

However, I have some users that have upwards of 300 likes.  For some reason one day the code returns 308 likes for the user, the next day it only returns 294.  I've checked with the user and they have not de-liked any posts on instagram.  Why would the count be going down?:

```
instagram = Instagram.client(access_token: #######)
total_likes_array = []
     liked1 = instagram.user_liked_media
     #.user_liked_media is a method native to the Instagram-ruby-gem 
     total_likes_array.push(liked1.size)
     liked_next_max_id = liked1.pagination.next_max_like_id
     #.pagination.next_max_like_id is a method native to the Instagram-ruby-gem
     while !liked_next_max_id.nil?
         liked_next = instagram.user_liked_media(max_like_id: liked_next_max_id)
         #max_like_id is a parameter in the Instagram-ruby-gem
         total_likes_array.push(liked_next.size)
         liked_next_max_id = liked_next.pagination.next_max_like_id
     end
total_likes = total_likes_array.sum
```

Comment: Because instagram has async replication it is possible that some servers don't have the latest follower count and are lagging behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It usually happens if the photo you liked has been deleted by the user who posted it.

Comment: This is not the answer I wanted (I wish there was something wrong with my code so at least the solution was in my control), but I think you're right.  Thanks for the input.  My best solution now is to re-code this so that I never re-check an old like (I should have been doing that from the beginning).  It's a major bummer that the instagram api has no "since_photo_id:" parameter that would allow me to check for likes since the last photo I checked.

Comment: Just found this answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896500/ruby-on-rails-instagram-gem-like-and-comment-count-not-working-properly?rq=1), which appears to be more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is this, which works well:

```
authorized = Authorization.find_by_user_id_and_provider(user, 'instagram')
instagram = Instagram.client(access_token: authorized.oauth_token)
user_id = authorized.user_id
current_instagram_user = InstagramUser.find_by_uid(authorized.uid)
user_data = instagram.user
total_likes_array = Array.new
current_max_liked_id = current_instagram_user.max_liked_id
# current_max_liked_id is the max_liked_id from the last DB entry.
if !current_max_liked_id.nil?
    liked_recent = instagram.user_liked_media # needs to run until current_max_liked_id
    if !liked_recent.empty?
        if current_max_liked_id.to_i <= liked_recent.first.id.to_i
            liked_first_max_id = liked_recent.first.id
        else
            liked_first_max_id = current_max_liked_id
        end
        liked_recent_max_id = liked_first_max_id # this is the highest like id available in the API request.
        until current_max_liked_id.to_i >= liked_recent_max_id.to_i
            liked_recent.each do |liked|
                if current_max_liked_id.to_i < liked.id.to_i
                    total_likes_array.push(x.id)
                elsif current_max_liked_id.to_i >= liked.id.to_i
                    break
                end
            end
            liked_recent_max_id = liked_recent.pagination.next_max_like_id
            liked_recent = instagram.user_liked_media(max_like_id: liked_recent_max_id)
        end
        num_likes_out = total_likes_array.size + current_instagram_user.int_likes_out           
        # use .size above because this is taking the total number of liked.id's in the array.
    end
else
    liked_first = instagram.user_liked_media
    if liked_first.empty?
        num_likes_out = 0
        liked_first_max_id = nil
    else
        total_likes_array.push(liked_first.size)
        liked_first_max_id = liked_first.first.id
        liked_next_max_id = liked_first.pagination.next_max_like_id
        while !liked_next_max_id.nil?
            liked_next = instagram.user_liked_media(max_like_id: liked_next_max_id)
            total_likes_array.push(liked_next.size)
            liked_next_max_id = liked_next.pagination.next_max_like_id
        end
        num_likes_out = total_likes_array.sum
        # take .sum above because the array shows total number of likes.
    end
end
```

Ultimately, `num_likes_out` is the outputted number of likes. I use `current_max_liked_id` to only check the instagram likes since the last like, and I run this code once a day in a scheduled rake job.