# Ruby on Rails Instagram Gem like and comment count not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3, instagram

I am trying to loop through data returned by Instagram and display information on a web page.
I can get literally every field to work EXCEPT for like or comment count.  For some reason, it always returns me the same number (2) for all the fields, even though if I look through the JSON returned the counts are clearly different.  Everything else works properly as it should.

More specifically, I am using the Ruby on Rails Instagram Gem, getting data using the tag_recent_media(user) method.

```
  def index
        result = []
        next_id = nil
        while result.length < 100
            data = Instagram.tag_recent_media(4, max_id: next_id)
            next_id = data.pagination.next_max_id
            result.concat(data)
        end

        @results = result.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)
  end
```

in my html.erb:

```
<% @results.each do |instagram| %>
instagram.images.standard_resolution.url //gives me image url correctly
instagram.caption.text //gives me caption text correctly
instagram.user.username //gives me the username correctly
instagram.likes.count //always gives me 2!
instagram.comments.count //always gives me 2!
<%end %>
```

anyone have any idea what might be going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [documented bug](https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem/issues/29) in the behavior of the Instagram Ruby Gem, *possibly* stemming from the word `count` being reserved.

It is suggested that the issue can be resolved by using a nested hash notation, rather than dot notation:

```
instagram.likes[:count]
instagram.comments[:count]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a `puts instagram.likes` and `puts instagram.comments`.  My bet is that likes and comments are returning an array or hash and you will need to go one level deeper to get the actual counts.